# Push JS and CSS to blob storage fails on one file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage

I have an azure devops pipeline that is taking the published artifacts from a build and pushing them up to blob storage in azure. Its currently failing, and it looks like its just on one file from the build output :

```
2021-05-25T13:31:27.4791037Z Job 01cfc270-4ee3-d341-5375-d4a214850167 has started
2021-05-25T13:31:27.4791930Z Log file is located at: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.azcopy\01cfc270-4ee3-d341-5375-d4a214850167.log
2021-05-25T13:31:27.4792379Z 
2021-05-25T13:31:27.4792564Z 
2021-05-25T13:31:27.7989703Z 0.0 %, 0 Done, 0 Failed, 2 Pending, 0 Skipped, 2 Total, 
2021-05-25T13:31:27.7998798Z INFO: AzCopy.exe: A newer version 10.10.0 is available to download
2021-05-25T13:31:27.7999390Z 
2021-05-25T13:31:29.4798448Z 0.0 %, 0 Done, 0 Failed, 2 Pending, 0 Skipped, 2 Total, 
2021-05-25T13:31:29.4799302Z 
2021-05-25T13:31:29.4799523Z 
2021-05-25T13:31:29.4800018Z Job 01cfc270-4ee3-d341-5375-d4a214850167 summary
2021-05-25T13:31:29.4800736Z Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0334
2021-05-25T13:31:29.4801101Z Number of File Transfers: 2
2021-05-25T13:31:29.4801456Z Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
2021-05-25T13:31:29.4801854Z Total Number of Transfers: 2
2021-05-25T13:31:29.4802216Z Number of Transfers Completed: 1
2021-05-25T13:31:29.4802560Z Number of Transfers Failed: 1
2021-05-25T13:31:29.4802915Z Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
2021-05-25T13:31:29.4803244Z TotalBytesTransferred: 82
2021-05-25T13:31:29.4803595Z Final Job Status: CompletedWithErrors
2021-05-25T13:31:29.4803756Z 
2021-05-25T13:31:29.5154984Z ##[debug]ExceptionMessage: AzCopy.exe exited with non-zero exit code while uploading files to blob storage.
2021-05-25T13:31:29.5798549Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;code={"Task_Internal_Error":"BlobUploadFailed"};]
```

In the build output I have a JS file and a CSS file. I cant tell from that output which one its failing on, and the error doesn't tell me much. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you check the blob container to see which file got uploaded?

Comment: So I have 2 files. styles.css and ins-calc.js
I tried uploading them one at a time, and it works. But when I use the source path as : 
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Widget Pipeline/Artifact/dist/*
It fails on one of the files.
At least the pipeline fails, but I can see the files did get uploaded correctly!

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that the css file is 0 bytes big. Dont know if that matters?
But then again when I specify the css file explicitly it does work...